# Stop arrow keys from scrolling through tabs on TabControl C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I need to keep the arrow keys from being able to scroll through my various tabs. Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason for not wanting that to happen?

Comment: yeah, I don't want the tabs to switch before the password is entered.

Comment: I'm shocked at how an answer is marked as a solution when it doesn't even work! The KeyPress event is not thrown for Arrow keys.

Comment: Matt, if you don't want the tabs to switch before anything happens, then you should be adding code to the TabControl's SelectedIndexChanged() event. in that case, it would have nothing to do with arrow keys being pressed. if you only trap arrow keys, then any other way of switching to another tab (like with a mouse click) would not be handled either. there are other ways too, so you truly want to add code to the SelectedIndexChanged() event of that tab control.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can trap event "KeyPress" for that control

then on the handle you have

```
System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e
```

You then check

```
if (e->KeyChar == [find the number representing the arrow key])
  e->Handled = true; // Meaning that no one will receive it afterwards
```

Comment: this is C++, not C#. the question asked for C#. (not that mind, but just pointing out.) I'm shocked at how an answer is marked as a solution when it doesn't even work! The KeyPress event is not thrown for Arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the following code

```
string tempstring = e.KeyValue.ToString();
if (tempstring == "37" || tempstring == "38" || tempstring == "39" || tempstring == "40")
{
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

I placed it inside of the tabControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) method.

Comment: Are you _really_ doing integer comparison by first converting to a string and then doing a string comparison?